# overflow-x hidden doesn´t let my content that is inside go out

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

i´m working with dropdowns using bootstrap, i have an div element called "side-menu" with
overflow-y:scroll; width:60px,

and inside of it i got dropdowns , as you know dropdowns has UL tags that holds the content you want to popup,

well i want to popup that content outside of my side-menu in the same position as my dropdown is even if i scroll my side-menu.

but seems that my "side-menu" has a overflow-x that doesn´t let my content go out even when i set overflow-x:hidden

any idea on how to do it ?

html:

```
<div class="side-menu">
         <ul class="main-navigation-menu">
                 <li class="dropdown">
                       <button class="item dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownChamados" data-toggle="dropdown" >

                       <div class="item-content">
                         <div class="item-media"><i class="ti-bar-chart"></i></div>
                         <div class="item-inner"> <span class="name"> Orçamentos</span> <i class="icon-arrow"></i></div>
                       <div>

                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-item sub-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownChamados">
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .side-menu{
        margin-top: 68px;
            position: fixed;
            float: left;
            width: 60px;
            padding: 0px !important;
            height: calc(100vh - 68px);
            border-right: 1px solid #c8c7cc;
            background-color: #FFF;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
    }
 .main-navigation-menu  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 60px;
        height: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        top: auto;
        width: 260px;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        border-color: #c8c7cc;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh ok I get it now, use javascript for that, here's the code:
`

```
<button /* attributes here */ onclick="showmenu()"></button>
<script>
    var dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").style.display;
    function showmenu()
  {
    if(dropdown=="block"){dropdown="none";}
    else if(dropdown=="none"){dropdown="block";}
    }
</script>
```

Here's the css to modify:

```
.side-menu
 {
   overflow:visible;
}
.dropdown-menu
{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry I did a mistake sending it in two minutes

Comment: here it is. Think it's the answer?

Comment: Talissom Junior PS: I've written only things to change, this is not the full code of course. Add onclick attribute to the button, then add the javascript code and set overflow-x of side-menu to visible, and set display property of dropdown-emnu to none

Comment: @TalissonJunior can you send me an html file where you put me the code that I may use and also a css file and I'll try to see ok?

Comment: sure , where can i send you?

Comment: here's my email : mohamed.elkhatri2002@gmail.com

Comment: So where's the file? I didn't get any mail

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use position absolute for submenu :

```
.submenu {
   position : absolute;
   top : 100px; /*position from top*/
   left : 100px; /*position from left*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you hide the overflow-x, it is expected not to show... *Duh*

Maybe try `overflow-x: visible` on `.side-menu` ?

Comment: i don´t want to make it visible , i think you didn´t understand my point